# Avoiding label text overlap in AmCharts' 3D cylinder charts

Tags: javascript, amcharts

I'm showing percentage values inside my chart columns but some of the labels overlap when the values are very small and are hard to read. I tried adjusting the font size but it's not helping. How can I show these labels without any overlap? Screenshot below.

[image: Chart screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there's very little that can be done as the library doesn't have any strategies to automatically avoid overlap outside of hiding the labels if there's not enough room by default with the default false setting for  [`showAllValueLabels`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#showAllValueLabels).

You can try tweaking the graph objects' [`labelOffset`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmGraph#labelOffset) property to shift the text up to see if that helps, but that's all you can do on the label side of things.

Alternatively, instead of using labels, just rely on the chart balloons that appear when hovering over the column. You can also enable the [`chartCursor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor), which shows all balloons within a category/date instead of just one of the balloons and they won't overlap. You can adjust the cursor's visibility and appearance as well.